# What is the best way to handle an API Response top level in Android using Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, retrofit2

I have a project that has user login system. In my project, I am using `Retrofit`. As you know, `Retrofit` has `onResponse` and `onFailure` methods.

What I want to achieve is to log users out whenever a call returns **401** error.

The first option is to log them out every time I make an API call, overriding `onResponse`.I can get HTTP Status Code from `Response` object calling `response.getRaw().code()`, and log user out if it is **401**. However, this is not a good approach.

If you have any advice for handling this situation top-level, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Retrofit or Retrofit2? Please don't just add both tags. If you use Retrofit2 adding an `Interceptor` is one way to do it in a top level way

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't mean to include Retrofit. I will fix it now. I am using Retrofit2. I also thought about `Interceptor`, but my method to logout is hosted in `Application` class, how would I access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, one way would be to use `Interceptors`.

You could add an interceptor with a callback to your `OkHttp` client to intercept all 401 Requests. Then just invoke the callback to notify your listener.

Be sure to add it as a `addNetworkInterceptor()`, since you need the live data and can safely ignore cached results.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new UnauthorizedInterceptor(myListener))
            .build();
```

Some sample code on how this could work (not tested):

```
public class UnauthorizedInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private Callback mCallback;

    public UnauthorizedInterceptor(Callback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (originalResponse.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            mCallback.onUserLoggedOut();
        }

        return originalResponse;
    }

    interface Callback {
        void onUserLoggedOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I have one last question. In this line,  `.addNetworkInterceptor(new UnauthorizedInterceptor(myListener))` do you pass `myListener` in createService method?

Comment: This wholly depends on your architecture and design. I'd put both into my application / singleton instance to access it from anywhere in the app. So I'd add it within the applications `onCreate`. There is, like with so many things, no right answer to this question